# Vuejs change router path based on radio button selection

Tags: vue.js, select, vue-router

I have a form that should redirect the users from one route to another. I want this redirection to be based on a radio button selection.

```
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option value="select1"Go to select1 component</option>
          <option value="select2">Go to select2 component</option>
          <option value="select3">Go to select3 component</option>
        </select>
```

This `select` element is in a form so I have submit/save button at the end. I also have 3 more components to redirect. When user selects the first one and clicks save, I want to redirect them to the select1 component and if they select the second, go to second one etc.

How do customize my router link based on this selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming i have following routes.

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: "select1",
    path: "/select1",
    component: Select1
  },
  {
    name: "select2",
    path: "/select2",
    component: Select2
  }
];
```

with below select dropdown

```
<select v-model="selected">
          <option value="select1"Go to select1 component</option>
          <option value="select2">Go to select2 component</option>
          <option value="select3">Go to select3 component</option>
</select>
```

we can use route api `push` method to navigate programmatically.

```
watch: {
    selected: function (val, oldVal) {
       /either of below can be used
      // this.$router.push({ val }); // by route name
      // this.$router.push({ path: `/${val}` }); //by route path
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the support it helped me a a lot. By the way I said they are radio button when I explain the question. Sorry about that it was a dropdown with 3 selections :)

Comment: it will work with radio button as well. Please do not forget to vote :)